# I`m working at weather application and got some problems with passing city to the url

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Application crases when I call the method. I think it might be not //correct passing city to the link

```
public async void dataByCity(string city)
    {
        var url = String.Format(
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city +
        "&units=metric&APPID="+AppID);           

        var json = await FetchAsync(url);

        JsonValue firstitem = json;
        var mydata = JObject.Parse(json);

        cityTextGlobal = city;

        string GovnoData = (mydata["main"]).ToString();

        //spliting string
        string[] values = GovnoData.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = values[i].Trim();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //tempGlobal = values[i];
                GovnoTemperature = values[i];
            }
        }
        tempGlobal = null;
        foreach (char c in GovnoTemperature)
        {
            if (c == '-' || char.IsDigit(c) == true || c == '.')
            {
                tempGlobal += c.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

"name" in the link below is the name of the city. The link I use is:
[enter link description here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%7B0%7D&lon=%7B1%7D&units=metric&APPID=cb613e81430eb868b89ee9a28f905f03)

similar method with passing coordinates works well:

```
public async void Data_down(double lat, double lon)
    {

        var url = String.Format(
          "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&units=metric&APPID=" + AppID);

        var json = await FetchAsync(url);

        JsonValue firstitem = json;
        var mydata = JObject.Parse(json);

        cityTextGlobal = (mydata["name"]).ToString();

        string GovnoData = (mydata["main"]).ToString();

        //spliting string
        string[] values = GovnoData.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = values[i].Trim();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //tempGlobal = values[i];
                GovnoTemperature = values[i];
            }
        }
        tempGlobal = null;
        foreach (char c in GovnoTemperature)
        {
            if (c == '-' || char.IsDigit(c) == true || c == '.')
            {
                tempGlobal += c.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `String.Format` if you are just appending strings? Nevertheless the url construction should work.

Comment: Where does your app crash exactly?

Comment: You are right. I dont need string.format() when I pass the city, but when I pass coordinates I need it because they both are double. And method with coordinates works well

Comment: It crashes somewhere here: 'var url = 
            "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city +
            "&units=metric&APPID="+AppID;

            var json = await FetchAsync(url);

            JsonValue firstitem = json;
            var mydata = JObject.Parse(json);'

Comment: I don't think that `String.Format` formats doubles in a different way than `ToString()` would if no formatting rules are provided. If you want to format double values you should call `ToString()` and provide formatting rules. After all you are not passing double values to`String.Format`. You are passing whole concatenated string.

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting when your app crashes?

Comment: Thank you very much. I deleted String.Format(). and now it looks like don`t crash. I try to test it. and if I will have troubles I will write here